# Generating an n-ary cartaesian product in LINQPad

Tags: c#, string, linqpad

```
void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Load model from file.
    var model = new Model();
    model.LoadVectors("model.bin");
    // Get 10 nearest words to user input
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Input 1 > ");
        String word1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(word1);

        String[] splitted = word1.Split(' ');

        List<String> set1 = new List<string>();
        List<String> set2 = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
        {


            foreach (var item in model.NearestWords(splitted[0], 150))
            {
                set1.Add(item.Key);
            }

            foreach (var item in model.NearestWords(splitted[1], 150))
            {
                set2.Add(item.Key);
            }

        }

        List<String> combinations = set1.SelectMany(a => set2.Select(n => String.Concat(a, " ", n))).ToList();

        List<String> str = new List<String>();
        List<String> result = new List<String>();
        str = Alternate_titles.Select(o => o.Alternate_title).ToList();
        str = str.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < combinations.Count; ++i){

            if(str.Contains(combinations[i])){

                result.Add(combinations[i]);

            }
        }

        var hash = new HashSet<string>(result);

        hash.Dump();

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The code that I wrote uses a word2vec library (just finding words that has semantic similarity with the input word) to match a job title with similar meaning.

If I input a job title `Software developer`, it will store top 150 similar words of `Software` in `set1` and similar word of `developer` in `set2`.

Then, `List<String> combinations = set1.SelectMany(a => set2.Select(n => String.Concat(a, " ", n))).ToList();`

this line generates a binary cartaesian product of strings in `set1` and `set2`.

Then,

```
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < combinations.Count; ++i){

        if(str.Contains(combinations[i])){

            result.Add(combinations[i]);

        }
    }
```

This part just checks if the `combination` (result of cartaesian product) is an actual job title in the database that I am using (`str` in this case).

Finally, it prints the result.

My question is, this code is only limited to binary cartaesian product, but it should work for any `n-ary` string. For example, it should do the same thing for `Software developer intern`.

Which part of the code do I have to modify to make this flexible and make it work for any n-ary string?

Comment: you should manipulate you loop and iterate over that splited string, I mean nested loop

Comment: I think you should use dynamic query for any string, because each string may have several word parts.

Comment: See my article on the subject for an implementation of n-ary Cartesian product; that should get you started. https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/